# App crashes when button onclicklistener is clicked to go to recycler view - don't know what is wrong

Tags: java, android

i'm new to android studio, and i'm currently trying to create an app that shows a recycler view of tourist attractions after switching to a new activity.

However, when i try to switch to the new activity with the recycler view from the landing page, the app crashes and i'm not sure why, any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

PS: There are no error messages and everything builds fine, so I'm not sure where to start

### Main Activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btEnter);
        //Enter into app main function button

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TopLocationList.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

### List of Locations activity code

```
public class TopLocationList extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    String s1[], s2[];
    int images[] = {R.drawable.sydneyoperahouse, R.drawable.bondi, R.drawable.botanicgardens, R.drawable.harbourbridgeclimb,
            R.drawable.rocks, R.drawable.thethreesisters, R.drawable.spicealley, R.drawable.thequay, R.drawable.mrwong,
            R.drawable.thegrounds, R.drawable.manly};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_location_list);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.top_location_names);
        s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.location_suburb);

        AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(this, s1, s2, images);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    }
}
```

### Adapter class code

```
public class AdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterClass.MyViewHolder> {
    String data1[], data2[];
    int images[];
    Context context;

    public AdapterClass(Context ct, String s1[], String s2[], int img[]){
        context = ct;
        data1 = s1;
        data2 = s2;
        images = img;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewrows, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mAttractionSuburb.setText(data1[position]);
        holder.mAttractionName.setText(data2[position]);
        holder.mImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data1.length;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView mAttractionName, mAttractionSuburb;
        ImageView mImage;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mAttractionName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionName);
            mAttractionSuburb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionSuburb);
            mImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivAttractionImage);
        }
    }
```

### Strings.xml code (i added a string array through here)

```
<string name="app_name">TourismGuide</string>
    <string-array name = "top_location_names">
        <item> Sydney Opera House </item>
        <item> Bondi Beach </item>
        <item> Royal Botanic Garden </item>
        <item> Harbour Bridge </item>
        <item> The Rocks </item>
        <item> Three Sisters Walk </item>
        <item> Taronga Zoo </item>
        <item> Spice Alley </item>
        <item> The Quay </item>
        <item> Mr Wong </item>
        <item> The Grounds of Alexandria </item>
        <item> Manly Beach </item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="location_suburb">
        <item> Sydney </item>
        <item> Bondi </item>
        <item> Sydney </item>
        <item> Sydney </item>
        <item> Sydney </item>
        <item> Katoomba </item>
        <item> Mosman </item>
        <item> Chippendale </item>
        <item> Sydney </item>
        <item> Wynyard </item>
        <item> Alexandria </item>
        <item> Manly </item>
    </string-array>
```

I'm really sorry if this is long, again any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that no error messages are displayed in the logcat after crash?

Comment: Well, you have to learn how to get to the logs/traces that tell you what exactly when wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this for example

Answer (score 0):

```
 recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(this, s1, s2, images);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
```

You need to first assign the Layoutmanager to the RecyclerView and then attach the adapter to your recyclerview.

> PS. Go through some tutorial for simple RecyclerView.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, i've changed this and it seems to be working fine now - will review the tutorials like you suggested

Comment: Awesome...see its that easy...u just need practise. If found useful do accept and upvote the ans for others to know the solution as well.